# Using JQuery to load page fragments (Use fragment CSS / Scripts)

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, widget

I have seen many similar questions, but not one that addresses this specifically.

For a web application, I have designed many specific dynamic "fragments" as  (for example, the current session's login status). These fragments are saved as incomplete html (incomplete jsp pages to be specific). They have no html or body tags. But have css styles an javascript files that are necessary for the fragment to work.

Fragment.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
[...]code and functions to use ajax request to load current name using sessions
</script>

<div id="userProfile">
<H1>Current User:<span id="name">NONE GIVEN</span></H1>
</div>
```

The goal would then be to use JQuery to load the fragment on the current page, adding css to keep it in a fixed position on the top right.

1. Regarding CSS when dynamically loading such fragments. If such a fragment is loaded using $("#someID").load(), the included CSS and JS links get loaded into the current container, making the html invalid?
2. Loading only the fragment using a selection in the url $("#someID").load("/fragments/Fragment.jsp #userProfile");, and then dynamically loading the css and js.

I think that adding the code statically to the page should be avoided, because the number of pages that use the fragment would result in having to make changes to many pages, leading to an unmanagable site.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be another dud question, let me give my take on it, and the solution I used. Keep in mind it may not be correct, as I just started web design.

-I am using Tomcat with Servlets/JSP as the server side, but this has no effect on creating and using the widgets.

fragment.jsp

```
<div id="widget">
This contains the widget html. For the example here is a div to fill with data dynamically
<div id="dynamic"></div>
</div>
```

fragment.js

```
function initiateFragment(){
  $.get(aUrl,function(data){
    //callback goes here
    $("body").append(data);
    $("#dynamic").html(//dynamic content for the div);
    $("#widget").css(//Add any css here, don't include it to force modularity);
    //Since I needed a login widget, I added css to move the div out of document flow and to the top right
    });
}
```

Now, just by calling initiateFragment() on my main page (make sure fragment.js is included), the fragment loads and appears.